# Populating listbox with a function that gets values from a table

Tags: javascript, php, listbox

I have 2 listboxes on my web page. I want to populate second listbox by a value selected in first list box. When I select an option in firstlistbox it queries a table on my backend and populates the secondlist box based on the results. I cannot use php script inside a javasript so what should I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how create a sub categories list box. You need create it easily using AJAX.

Here are the steps you need to do.

1. Populate first list box and call function loadData() when you change item.
2. send ajax request to getdata.php with selected category_Id parameter
3. Make getdata.php to output second list box according to category_Id
4. Display ajax response on page as html

I found [this](http://crewow.com/PHP_Dynamic_Select_option_Via_Ajax.php) article for you.

Hope it helps.